# Comparing values of a list with multiple list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to compare y with x, such that it will return the amount of matches and it strictly follows the value of y.

For example, in this scenario, it should return a count of 2 as there are 2 matches of ['a', 'b'].

```
x = ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'c'], ['a', 'b']
y = ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: `x.count(y)`..?

Comment: thank you yes it works, cause I cant seem to find this anywhere in my search, sorry for such a question

Comment: Uh, just realized you have a tuple rather than a list... oh well, it does have a count method, too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the list 'count' method.

```
x = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'c'], ['a', 'b']]
y = ['a', 'b']

my_count = x.count(y) # 2
```

Comment: Hi, will there be a difference if I create an overall list for these lists compared to if I separate them by their individual lists? Thank you!

Comment: When you don't wrap them, it automatically wraps them in a tuple. So not wrapping them like you did is the same as ```x = (['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'c'], ['a', 'b'])```. But it wouldn't differ in this case.

Comment: Tuples are similar to lists but the key difference is that tuples are immutable, which means it cannot be changed *(e.g. cannot append elements to a tuple)*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, the result will be 2, so you have to iterate through the x list and for each value compare it with y, right?

```
x = [['a', 'b'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'c'], ['a', 'b']]
y = ['a', 'b']
sum = 0
for i in x:
  if i == y:
    sum+=1
print(sum)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this method and I dont think it will probably work. If I am not wrong, such lists are unable to read as an index, or I am not sure is there another way round to make it work such that it is able to read it as an index. Thank you!